# What is a 'reasonable' ordinary differential equation question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello although I can answer some ODE questions I don't think I have fully understood the topic.

My question is

Which of the following problems are 'reasonable' and why ? You do not need to solve the ODE's to answer this question ?

1)  dy/dx = f(x)h(y) ,  y(1)=y(2)=0

The answer to this is it's not reasonable because there are too many conditions (two) for a first order differential equation.

I just don't understand what this means ? There are also more questions i need to answer but I don't understand what is a 'reasonable' ODE.

I was hoping someone could explain the question with or without an example I have written above and maybe give a summary about types of ODE and what makes them reasonable. I have tried looking on google and textbooks but I just don't understand. Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: That's a non-standard term.  I expect the writer means "overdetermined" or something like that.  The problem being that too many initial conditions are specified and that, as a result, there need not be any solutions.